# Converting bulk data to .csv

Tags: windows

I am attempting to write a conversion to take data from one format to present it as a csv.
the current format of the file is as such for a single row on a spreadsheet and only the fields with the column ID would be pulled

```
01*A*B*C*D*E*F*G*H*I*J*K*L*M*
02*N*O*P*Q*R*
03*S*T*U*V*W*X*Y*Z*AA*AB*AC*AD*AE*
04**********
04**********
04**********
05*AF*AG*
06*AH*AI*AJ*AK*
06*AL*AM*AN*AO*
07*AP*AQ*
07*AR*AS*
08*AT*AU*AV*AW*AX*AY*AZ*BA*BB*BC*BD*BE*
09*******
```

the issue is that the lines beginning with 04 and 06 can vary in quantity depending on the ammount of data contained for that listing. All lines beginning with 04 and 09 will be ignored and any lines that begin with 06 that exceed the first two would also be ignored but if there is only one line beginning with 06 the second's columns need to be preserved. I am not picky about language for this as long as i can do it in windows, I have just hit a brick wall with my own limited programming experience

Comment: what code have you written?

Comment: ... in what languages? Since it's just text filtering (I think?) what's the most appropriate language that you know?

Answer (score 1):

Your example data is a relatively common EDI format so the problem you need to overcome is to know when your record starts and when it finishes.  Normally you read the file stream up to the newline (in other words, you are reading 1 line at a time).  When the entry point of a record is detected, the line starting with "01*" in your example, you create an inner loop to read lines either to include or ignore depending on what your specific needs may be.  An object can loaded within the loop quite easily.  Once a record is finished (by your "09*") you then have an object representing a record that can be used for further processing, saving, exporting... whatever you need to do.

I think the larger problem for you is your self-stated limited programming experience.  You don't specific what language(s) you are using?  Rather than trying to solve a specific problem right out of the gates, I'd suggest familiarizing yourself with development languages and the pros/cons considering your target platform.  Furthermore I'd advise against file I/O as one of your first experiences with programming as far too many traps exist.
I won't turn your question into a "what is the best language" debate, but give these a read and decide if you can dedicate some time to further learning -

- Visual Basic:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172579(v=vs.80).aspx
- Python: http://www.sthurlow.com/python/
- Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/

If you don't have the free cycles to learn a specific language to any degree, might I suggest some of the very powerful "data transformation" products (aka ETL tools).  With these visual tools you could define a source file, how the data is offered up, and how to mutate the output.  These offer plenty of options for the non-programmers and in many cases can be every bit as good as custom written software.
Here is one such tool that I've used with a lot of success in the past -

http://www.pentaho.com/explore/pentaho-data-integration/